# PHP - PayPal integration - Payments to multiple accounts

Tags: php, authentication, curl, paypal, payment

I and another programmer have been at this for a few days with no joy. All we are trying to accomplish at this point is to receive a successful response from PayPal. Unfortunately the PayPal API is woefully documented.

Here is our code:

```
    <?php
    class Paypal {
            /**
            * Last error message(s)
            * @var array
            */
            protected $_errors = array();

            /**
            * API Credentials
            * Use the correct credentials for the environment in use (Live / Sandbox)
            * @var array
            */
            protected $_credentials = array(
                    'USER' => '*************************',
                    'PWD' => '****************',
                    'SIGNATURE' => '************************************************',
            );

            /**
            * API endpoint
            * Live - https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
            * Sandbox - https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
            * @var string
            */
            protected $_endPoint = 'https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay';

            /**
            * API Version
            * @var string
            */
            protected $_version = '74.0';


            public function newstartpayment() {
                    //set PayPal Endpoint to sandbox
                    $url = trim("https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay");

            //PayPal API Credentials
            $API_UserName = $_credentials['USER'];
            $API_Password = $_credentials['PWD'];
            $API_Signature = $_credentials['SIGNATURE'];

            //Default App ID for Sandbox    
            $API_AppID = "******************";

            $API_RequestFormat = "NV";
            $API_ResponseFormat = "NV";

            //Create request payload with minimum required parameters
            $bodyparams = array (
                    "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage" => "en_US",
                    "actionType" => "PAY",
                    "currencyCode" => "USD",
                    "cancelUrl" => "http://www.paypal.com",
                    "returnUrl" => "http://www.paypal.com",
                    "receiverList.receiver(0).email" => "************@paypal.com", //TODO
                    "receiverList.receiver(0).amount" => "40", //TODO
                    "receiverList.receiver(0).primary" => "true", //TODO
                    "receiverList.receiver(1).email" => "****************@paypal.com", //TODO
                    "receiverList.receiver(1).amount" => "30", //TODO
                    "receiverList.receiver(1).primary" => "false", //TODO
                    'USER' => '************************',
                    'PWD' => '***********',
                    'SIGNATURE' => '*************************************'
            );

            // convert payload array into url encoded query string
            $body_data = http_build_query($bodyparams, "", chr(38));

            try
            {
                    //create request and add headers
                    $params = array("http" => array( 
                    "method" => "POST",
                    "content" => $body_data,
                    "header" => "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: " . $API_UserName . "\r\n" .
                    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: " . $API_Signature . "\r\n" .
                    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: " . $API_Password . "\r\n" .
                    "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: " . $API_AppID . "\r\n" .
                    "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: " . $API_RequestFormat . "\r\n" .
                    "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: " . $API_ResponseFormat . "\r\n" 
                    ));

                    //create stream context
                    $ctx = stream_context_create($params);

                    //open the stream and send request
                    $fp = @fopen($url, "r", false, $ctx);

                    //get response
                    $response = stream_get_contents($fp);

                    //check to see if stream is open
                    if ($response === false) {
                            throw new Exception("php error message = " . $php_errormsg);
                    }

                    //close the stream
                    fclose($fp);

                    return $response;
            }
                    catch (Exception $e) {
                            error_log($e->getMessage());
                            print_r($e);
                            return false;
                    }
    }

    $paypal = new Paypal();

    ?>
```

Ok, Now when this code is executed, we get the following error:

> Paypal returned: 2012-02-19T15:07:01.883-08:00Failureff3b99b56fcb72486531520003PLATFORMApplicationErrorApplicationAuthentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.

We are at the end of our ropes, please for the love of god help..

Comment: "API credentials are incorrect. " error seems clear.

Comment: API credentials thoroughly checked, 1000's of times, they are correct.

Comment: Are they credentials from a live account? That won't work against the Sandbox endpoint, or vice versa. Get a test seller account via https://developer.paypal.com/ > Test accounts > preconfigured and use those API credentials instead.

Answer (score 0):

you are using pypal sandbox or live paypal API credentials.

Comment: sandbox. We are testing in sandbox. so the accounts are sandbox